# How to Split and Extract Characters from A String Using One Expression in Regex

Tags: regex

Example:

```
aaa.bbbb.ccc4.ddd1.eee.fff
1112.2223.333.4445.555.6661.7773.8881.999
```

And how to return `ddd` and `777` using one expression, where they are always the first 3 characters of last third string between dots.

I know how to do this in two expression:

```
`[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$`
`^\w{3}`
```

Is there a way to combine them together? And the second expr is applied to not the original but the result of the first expr?

Comment: Use a capturing group `([^.]{3})[^.]*\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$` https://regex101.com/r/OFwqa2/1

Comment: Nice. Thanks! Capturing group is the thing I am missing :D

Comment: you could also use: `([^.]{3})(?=(?:.\.[^.]*){2}$)` https://regex101.com/r/ukI7ht/2

Comment: @Onyambu good alternative! Works well in php. How about in golang? I have `? The preceding token is not quantifiable`

Comment: @JvdV just edited it. Realized OP needed only 3

Comment: @LucasH.Xu just change the `=` in the above to `:` it should still work since you are interested in the first captured group

Comment: @Onyambu perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @JvdV did not see that. Sorry `([^.]{3})(?=(?:[^.]*\.[^.]*){2}$)` should satisfy everything you say

Comment: @Onyambu, I guess a non-capture group is a valid option if you move the first negated dot outside the (unnessecary) lookahead. I guess `\.([^.]{3})[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){2}$` is what you were after.

Comment: @JvdV it will depend on the engine. If using PCRE, I would rather place it in the lookahead uncaptured group. But using golang, you will have it outside the group. Here, OP did not specify which engine is being used

Comment: If you do so you'll have multiple matches on for example `aaa.bbbb.ccc4.dddddd1.eee.fff`. Sorry for nitpicking =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  match a dot, and capture 3 characters in a capturing group followed by matching 0+ times any char except a dot till the next dot.

Then match the last 2 parts and assert the end of the string.

```
\.([^.]{3})[^.]*\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETnPVb/1)

If there is nothing preceding, you could either match a dot or assert the start of the string.

```
(?:^|\.)([^.]{3})[^.]*\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXlopi/1)

**Note** that a `[^.]` can also match a space or a newline. Use `\S` to match a non whitespace char.

Answer (score 3):

You could match the regular expression

```
(?<=\.).{3}(?=[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){2}$)
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/3kzEXr/1/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=\.)        : positive lookbehind asserts previous
                 char was '.'
.{3}           : match 3 chars
(?=            : begin positive lookahead
  [^.]*        : match 0+ chars other than '.'
  (?:\.[^.]*)  : match '.' then 0+ chars other than
                 '.' in a non-capture group
  {2}          : execute non-capture group twice
  $            : assert end of string
)              : end positive lookahead
```

Another way would be to use the regular expression

```
(?=\.(.{3})[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*){2}$)
```

capturing the desired 3-character string in capture group 1.

[Restart engine](https://regex101.com/r/3kzEXr/2/)

```
(?=            : begin positive lookahead
  \.           : match '.'
  (.{3})       : match 3 chars in capture group 1
  [^.]*        : match 0+ chars other than '.'
  (?:\.[^.]*)  : match '.' then 0+ chars other than
                 '.' in a non-capture group
  {2}          : execute non-capture group twice
  $            : assert end of string
)              : end positive lookahead
```

If the match succeeds an empty string at the beginning of the string is matched, but it is the contents of capture group 1 that is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/CCZ45U/1) is another option:

```
(?=(\.[^.]*){3}$)\.(.{3})
```

Where you'd match:

- `(?=` - Positive lookahead.

  - `(\.[^.]*){3}` - 1st Capture group to match a literal dot, anything but a dot zero or more times. Repeat capture group three times.
  - `$)` - End string ancor and close lookahead.
- `\.` - A literal dot.
- `(.{3})` - 2nd Capture group to capture first three digits after the dot.

Extract from 2nd capture group. Or if you want you could use a non-catpure group and capture from 1st capture group: `(?=(?:\.[^.]*){3}$)\.(.{3})`